# Adding image to UIButton makes it unclickable

Tags: swift, xcode

I am learning to navigate and use the features of Xcode right now and I don't understand why adding an image to a UIButton through the Attributes Inspector makes the UIButton unclickable. When adding the image, it also resizes the button on the storyboard. I can't seem to find any answers online. Could somebody explain why this behavior occurs?

Before adding the image to the UIButton:

[image]

After adding the image to the UIButton:

[image]

Edit: and preferably how to fix it :D

Comment: Can you show us the code where you instantiate the button (with the addTarget, preferably)

Comment: @Francis.Beauchamp I have not applied any code yet. I'm pretty new to this and I simply don't understand why adding an image through Xcode (no code involved) would result in the UIButton becoming unclickable.

Comment: Is the type of the button set to "Custom"? If not, set it to "Custom" first and try again.

Comment: @Sulthan Yeah, it's set to custom. The issue seems to be the animation not appearing when you click a button. It should indicate that you are touching the button, but it does not :(

Comment: @Kentah The highlighting is done by changing the background image (the setting is called "dim background on highlight" or something similar. It does not change the background color.

Comment: @Sulthan Are you thinking of "adjustImageWhenHighlighted"? I tried setting it to true (which should be the default value), but I still can't see the indicator of whether you press a button or not. This is rather strange and quite annoying.. :/

Comment: @Sulthan Alright.. setting the type of the button to "System" apparently made it work properly...

Answer (score 0):

The unclickable scenario you described is literally impossible unless you deleted everything in the connections inspector tab. In order for the image not to resize you should use autolayout in the bottom right. Set a constraint on width and height.

Comment: Setting the constraints fixed the resizing. I just tested to see if the button can change the text of a label and it seems it can, but I can't see the animation of when you click a button. I guess that's the real issue. I'm not sure why I did not test this in the first place... I guess I didn't think of it :(